# Creating a profile for users model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users model in my rails application. It has a name attribute only along with email & password added to it for login via Devise. I want to create a model Profile for users. How shall I create it. Either by adding profile attributes to existing User model or by creating a model Profile and adding a belongs_to association to it.

Comment: Personally, if the profile data were relatively stable, I would create a profile model and add a belongs_to to it, or maybe a has_one to users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it depends on the requirements you have.

If a user can have only one `profile` and you are just going to add some attributes related to the `user`, there is no reason to create a new class to it.

However, even if a user can have only one profile, you might want to do some [normalisations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If so, you might remove some attributes from the `users` table to create a table `profiles`, and you will have a one-to-one relationship.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end 

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Well... depending on your requirements, you might have a situation where a user might have more than one profile. If so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
end 

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

To summarise, there is no right or wrong... it will depend on the requirements you have, as well as you design decision.

Comment: Is it possible to create a profile module and include it into the User model as I want to create profiles for different types of users e.g. student, teacher, principal, which would have some common attributes and some different from each other ?

Comment: not really... you can use modules and inheritances in other situation. For example, if you have the following classes: `student`, `teacher`, `staff`, etc. All of them have things in comum, like `name`, `age`, etc. AND the relationship with other tables are different. In this case, you can use modules or inheritances to avoid to add all comum attributes in every single class. However, in your case I don't think you need it.. you can just add an attribute `type` to specify the level of access (I think it is what you want). So, if the current_user has type student you can block some actions...

Comment: However, if `student`, `teacher` and `principal` have different behaviours, well... then you should think about different classes...

Answer (score 6):

Adding more attributes to your user model will make your user object a bit heavy and is not the best idea given that you'll be calling that object quite often.  For instance, to verify a user, you don't need to load the profile attributes like location or date of birth, which the current_user helper would.  So, its better to extract profile attributes in a separate model and adopt either of  gabreilhilal's approaches.